# How to increase size of Desktop alert message popup of outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

How to increase size of  Desktop alert message popup of outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can only change its position, time to display and transparency.

See Microsoft's [Customize Desktop Alerts](https://web.archive.org/web/20100318055432/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP010416051033.aspx).

Comment: broken link....

Comment: @DavidPostill: Replaced with Wayback Machine Archive link.

Answer (score 1):

Again I can recommend [Mail Alert](http://www.bettasoft.net/mailalert). You can fully customize it to suite your needs including changing the size of alert windows.

Comment: Looks like you like Mail Alert a lot! :-)